# Google Sheets forumla to lookup and populate multiple rows and columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I need to do something like a vlookup but to populate multiple columns. Heres my sheet:

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QsarnElwfKplVOsHo_i9mebL36dqsRxbQJUsQ1MeNdk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes tried the following but it only populates the first row:
=QUERY(Sheet2!A:F, "Select A,B,C,E,F where D matches '"&A2&"' ")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this formula in **B1** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1:A, {Sheet2!D1:D, Sheet2!A1:F}, {2,3,4,6,7}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]